# The figures from $1$ to $120$ were made in $15$ rows. Which column has the largest sum of the numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

[image]

> **Question**: The figures from $1$ to $120$ were made in $15$ rows. Which column has the largest sum of the numbers? (*Starting from the left*)

I tried only with calculating. I could not find an elegant way. I'm looking for a simple solution that does not require calculation. Because this is the exam question. We have up to maximum 2-3 minutes.

Comment: I'd say $2-3$ minutes was more than enough to add each column.  As you will have observed, The two columns with the greatest sums are very close in total...hard to see which is greater without some computing.

Comment: What if you focus on just the first two columns? Can you find a way to decide which has the greater sum, without calculating the sums? Ask yourself what the differences are between the two columns.

Comment: If you want a quick trick, note that subtracting $1$ from each entry in a column gives you all but one term of the column to the left of it.  That lets you compare consecutive columns very quickly.

Comment: @lulu I've already lost my chance. I'm working for 1 hour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say the sum of the 15 numbers in the first column is $S_1$. Then notice that in the second column, you have 14 numbers so you remove $1$ from the sum and you add $14$ to the sum (since these numbers are $1$ more than the numbers in the same row). So you have $S_2 = S_1-1+14 = S_1+13$. Then in the third column, you remove $3$ from the sum $S_2$ and add $13$ to the sum, which is $S_3 = S_2-3+13 = S_2+10$. In the fourth column, you remove $6$ from the sum $S_3$ and you add $12$ to the sum so $S_4 = S_3-6+12 = S_3+6$. Finally, in the fifth column, you remove $10$ from the sum $S_4$ and you add $11$ to the sum so $S_5 = S_4-10+11 = S_4+1$. Notice that after this step, your sum will be less than the sum in the previous column so the answer must be the fifth column.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. There are $15$ columns and the $n$-column start with $n(n+1)/2$ and has $16-n$ numbers. 
Note that the difference between the sum of the numbers in the $n$-th column and the sum of the numbers in the $(n+1)$-th column is
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\underbrace{-1-1\dots-1}_{16-(n+1)}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}-16.$$
The change of sign of the above difference will tell you where the maximum is.

P.S. Note that the number $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$ appears at the top of the $(n+1)$-th column, so you don't have to calculate it...

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n$ denote the sum of the $n^{th}$ column.

Then the sum of the immediate left column is $S_{n-1}= S_n + (15 - n) + {n(n+1) \over 2}$

The maximum will occur the first time when ${n(n+1) \over 2}$ exceeds $(15-n)$ and this happens on the $5^{th}$ column.